# How do I keep a head pointer in a Linked List from being reasigned when iterating through it?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to implement a Linked List in C++, and initialize it using the following:

```
ListNode *ll = new ListNode(0);
ListNode *head = ll;
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    ll->next = &ListNode(i);
    ll = ll->Next;
}
```

The problem is that during each iteration, when ll is reassigned to point to it's next, the head pointer also gets reassigned. So, after each iteration, `head` pointer looks like this:

0 -> 1

0 -> 2

0 -> 3

...

0 -> 8

Instead of what it should be:

0 -> 1 -> 2 ... -> 8

How do I keep the Head pointer from being changed when I move the iterative pointer?

Here's struct ListNode:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
} typedef ListNode;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a big problem in your code:

```
temp->next = &ListNode(i);
```

This tries to get the address of the temporary variable and store it somewhere. But temporary is eradicated right after you move to the next line, so you end up with an address pointing to garbage.

By the way, this should not be even compilable, so if your compiler allows this, that's a bug in the compiler.

Comment: I didn't know that. I am using Visual C++, and it compiled correctly. Based on what you said, I replaced that line of code with `ll->next = new ListNode(i);`, and it fixed the problem I was getting. However, is using the new operator the most efficient way of initializing a Linked List, or should I be initializing it differently?

Comment: @iamseiko, now you have freed yourself from **undefined behaviour**. The behaviour of your program is well-defined. However, you have another problem at hand - you have a pointer which needs to be managed. You need to take care of it. You need to make sure to clean it up when it's no longer needed, you need to make sure copying or assigning your nodes is sane in regards to this pointer.

Comment: What I see is that the pointer to the temp node is kept after the loop ends. So, instead of directly assigning it, I should save it in a variable `ListNode *newNode`, `newNode = new ListNode(i)` in each iteration. And when the loop ends, I call `delete newNode`. Is that what you mean?